# Software Updater 14.04 LTS to 16.04.5 LTS upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Will upgrading through Software Updater keep data, file folders, and installed software such as "Audacity?"

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is supposed to do so yes. However it is highly recommended to make a copy of your files because upgrading a version is sensitive process that can result in unexpected issues. Regarding to applications, you should keep them as well, unless the version upgrade introduces some incompatibilities with your current applications.